# Is there a way to graphically analyze frequency of samples/instruments in Renoise?

Tags: mixing, daw, equalization

There's a master spectrum view but is there a way to use some static graphical representation of the frequency spectrum to adjust the different samples/instruments?

Something to make it easier to play with the EQ of the tracks with graphical feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Renoise, but according to [this tutorial](http://tutorials.renoise.com/wiki/VST/AU/LADSPA_Effects) it's possible to configure VSTs for a Windows environment.

So, if you're using Windows, [here's your solution](http://www.best-free-vst.com/plugins/effects/audio-signal-spectrum-analyzer-01.php):

I personally use [MAnalyzer](http://www.meldaproduction.com/freevstplugins/manalyzer.php).

If you don't like any of the solutions OR you're not using Windows you should try googling:
spectrum analyzer

I'm aware that you did ask for a 'static' graphical analyzer, but I'm wondering if you're problem is that the master spectrum is capturing the whole song instead of a single channel.

And btw: I really wouldn't recommend anyone to do audio changes based on a graphical spectrum - music is about what you hear, and not what you listen.

While doing that is fine when experimenting, it shouldn't become something you do all the time.